# Difference between electric and magnetic force

Tags: electromagnetism

I watched the video which says that electric and magnetic forces are one and the same thing it is just that when electric Field when viewed from different frame of reference becomes electric field the link for the video is given below .

---

My confusion is that if the two forces are same and differ only in frame of reference will there magnitude ne always same and what is the need to segregate the forces then.is there something related to newtonian mechanics which alks about forces in inertial and non inertial frame of reference 
https://youtu.be/1TKSfAkWWN0

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21238/238167 and the links therein

Comment: Not perfectly I want to know its dependence on newtonian Mechanics and whether their magnitudes are dependent on one another or not also I want to know that the statement written above is always true or are their some exceptions